# IE7 & IE8 <hgroup> background color

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, internet-explorer-7

For some odd reason any background styles I set on my  (being loaded within a modal if that makes any difference) are not rendering in IE7 or IE8.  It all looks completely fine in all other (real) browsers (including IE9).  My code is as follows:

```
<hgroup>
<h6>Request Information Form</h6>
 <a href="#" onClick="closeModal(); return false;"><img src="/images/x-close.png" alt="Close" class="close" /></a>
</hgroup>
```

I know you aren't supposed to put anything besides `<h1>-<h6>` within an `<hgroup>`, but I need this little close img in there, and even when I've tried pulling it out, I ran into the same problem (plus it all "seems" to validate).

The CSS is:

```
hgroup {
position: relative;
width: 668px;
height: 32px;
margin: 0 0 16px;
padding: 14px 14px 0 14px;
background: #B66115 url(/images/modal_header_bckgrnd.png) repeat-x 0 0;
font: normal 20px/20px 'crimson Text',Georgia,serif;
color: #F6F5EE;
}
```

Also, I have declared `<hgroup>` as `display:block`, and I am using the IE shim.  All I keep getting is a white background (which really doesn't work when I have white text in the block!).

Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Comment: hgroup was introduced as part of HTML 5 as far as I know IE7 and IE8 do not support this tag.

Answer (score 3):

IE7 and IE8 do not load html5 tag names into the document.  Any unrecognized tags are ignored.  Try adding a bit of javascript to manually add them (or use something like modernizr.js).

```
<script>
document.createElement('header');
document.createElement('hgroup');
document.createElement('nav');
document.createElement('section');
document.createElement('article');
document.createElement('aside');
document.createElement('footer');
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

> being loaded within a modal if that
>   makes any difference

Does your modal window use an `iframe`?

If so, you also need to run your HTML5 element shim script inside the `iframe`.

Comment: Just discovered that just before you posted this answer...I checked the code again, and since this was a modal, using Shadowbox, we were loading this form as an iFrame, and the Shim was not declared in the header of the page being loaded into the modal...thus no HTML5 recognition.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [HTML5 Shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/).

On a slightly unrelated note, you're using `<hgroup>` incorrectly. It's only supposed to contain one or more hN elements, and nothing more.

Using your code above, you should be using `<header>` instead.